# why Tensorflow object detection API predicting one class for all object?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, tensorflow, object-detection

I used Tensorflow object deteciton API following this [tutorial](https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10) and trained it to predict custom images of three category. After 49K steps and with most loss < 0.05 I stopped and froze the model. When i try to detect the object from image. The model correctly detects the object but provides wrong class label also it only gives one label for all detected object. I have checked the test.Record and train.Record which correctly captures the bounding box coordinates and class/class_text. I tried debugging the prediction model and found the below scores: This output is class and score for that particular class for each proposal. It returns 300 proposal value but i edited just for the question.

> **Classes**:
>   [[2. 1. 3. 3. 2. 2. 1. 3. 2. 1. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 1. 2. 2. 3.
>   2.
>     3. 2. 2. 2. 2. 3. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 1. 2. 2. 3. 2. 2. 2.
>     2. 2. 1. 2. 2. 1. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 3. 2.
>     2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 3. 2. 2. 2. 1.
>     2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 3. 2. 2. 2. 1. 2. 2. 2. 2. 3. 3. 2. 2.]]
>
> **Scores**
>     [[9.34299827e-01 9.87844169e-02 7.54007278e-03 3.31299962e-04
>     8.95422545e-06 8.40702705e-06 7.37192840e-06 2.25948543e-06
>     1.55862494e-06 1.32166167e-06 9.75570629e-07 5.88678745e-07
>     5.05015009e-07 4.21588567e-07 2.58588926e-07 2.14299249e-07
>     1.97753181e-07 1.18188609e-07 7.23913232e-08 6.49422844e-08
>     6.09321731e-08 5.54216335e-08 4.88208514e-08 4.80325468e-08
>     4.59127847e-08 4.42321024e-08 4.26271001e-08 3.75534768e-08]]

The correct class label was 3 which has very low score comparing to other 2 class. For this checkpoint it favors class 2, I tried retraining and stopped early then found the model skewed to different class. but all of them consist of exponential scores. When I tried using the tutorial dataset and record file it contained 6 classes. With early stop I got different normalized output and more importantly it was able to predict more than one class though the accuracy was poor the scores were normal.

> **Classes:**
>   [[1. 6. 6. 6. 1. 1. 1. 5. 6. 1. 6. 6. 1. 6. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 6. 6. 3. 3.
>   3.
>     3. 1. 5. 4. 3. 1. 3. 5. 1. 2. 2. 5. 1. 3. 5. 3. 6. 6. 6. 5. 3. 4. 1. 4.
>     1. 2. 3. 5. 6. 4. 3. 4. 3. 4. 3. 3. 1. 5. 4. 2. 6. 4. 3. 4. 3. 2. 2. 2.
>     1. 6. 2. 3. 3. 6. 2. 6. 2. 1. 1. 4. 4. 2. 3. 2. 4. 4. 3. 4. 2. 4. 4. 4.]]
>
> **Scores**
>   [[0.8057396  0.54363483 0.41639847 0.4116147  0.40117604 0.30583626
>     0.28162587 0.19588488 0.17949946 0.17705482 0.14739332 0.1368773
>     0.11625872 0.09852906 0.09733354 0.09538303 0.09463519 0.07830063
>     0.07063951 0.06350185 0.06187743 0.05515279 0.05392814 0.05084944
>     0.04962941 0.04584368 0.04244312 0.04015012 0.03859867 0.03793424
>     0.03495875 0.03406471 0.03277094 0.03216837 0.03211389 0.0311062
>     0.03045315 0.03031772 0.02878817 0.02855495 0.02775684 0.02764305
>     0.02756038 0.0258495  0.02555148 0.02552066 0.02524703 0.0251481
>     0.02503884 0.024954   0.02364612 0.02353399 0.02353344 0.02315213
>     0.0230271  0.02294012 0.02266986 0.02261656 0.02215081 0.02189769]]

I want to know why after so many steps and with very less value my model is performing very poorly and why it stuck to single class. How can I solve this issue ?

I am using 600 images as trianing and 72 as validation. I used labelIMG to crop the images.

Comment: You really need to give us more details for this to be answerable, otherwise your question is "I ran some model and it doesn't work".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be caused by overfitting or by inbalanced data set. Look at [documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_locally.md#running-the-evaluation-job)  how to run evaluation job simultaneously to see how good is yout net performing. Tensorboard is a good tool to visualise what is going on.

Model gets often stuck to a single class, when your dataset is inbalanced, it means when your data contains too many examples of that class.

Comment: Yeah i figured out the issue with the data set. But in my case the variation among the data in single class caused this confusion. thanks for the information about eval.

Comment: Hi Unbanned, I am facing a similar issue and the variations within one class is kind of extreme. What methods did you use to alleviate this issue?